# Language of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How  can we  represent $x$ is an $n$-ary function from $y$ to $z$  in language  of set theory.  We have written "$x$ is an ordered pair" in language of set theory  as " $[\exists v(\exists u (x=(v, u)))].$". Like this how can we write the above  statement.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

We almost always work in an "extension by definitions" of the language of set theory.  Once we can prove in the original language of set theory that a proposed definition is in fact well defined, we can then use a new symbol for that definition.  This is proper and appropriate because it's possible to prove that the extension by definitions is "conservative," which means that (a) any statement in the extension that uses only the original language of your theory is provably equivalent to the same statement in the original theory, and (b) any statement in the extension is provably equivalent to some statement made only in the language of your original theory.  In other words, you're not really adding or changing anything by making your language more convenient.

I bring this point up because ordered pairs aren't of course, expressed in the original language of set theory.  But in the same way you can extend by definitions to get to ordered pairs, you can extend by definitions to get to ordered $n$-tuples, usually denoted by $\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n \rangle$.

To write $x$ is an $n$-ary function from $y$ to $z$, we would write

$$(w \in x \iff (\exists x_1\exists x_2 \ldots \exists x_n \exists v_1 (w= \langle x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n, v_1 \rangle \land x_1 \in y \land x_2 \in y \land \ldots \land x_n \in y \land v_1 \in z \land \forall v_2 \langle x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n, v_2 \rangle \in x \Rightarrow v_1 = v_2)) \land (\forall x_1 \forall x_2 \ldots \forall x_n (x_1 \in y \land x_2 \in y \land \ldots \land x_n \in y \
\Rightarrow \exists v \in z \langle x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n, v \rangle \in x). $$

In English, the first clause says that $x$ consists of $n+1$-tuples, which we'll call $w$.  Each $w$ starts with $n$ elements of $y$ and ends with one element of $z$, and if two members of $x$ use the same $n$ members of $y$ in the same order, they also end up with the same element of $z$ in the last position.  That tells us that $x$ is a function with domain contained in $y^n$.  The final clause says that each $n$-tuple of elements from $y$ results in an element of $x$.  That tells us that the domain of $x$ is all of $y^n$.